# Change in URL directory when going from localhost to live site?

Tags: wordpress, localhost

If I develop multiple websites for clients locally, I like to keep them in their own folders. However, when I move these to the client's live site, how do I change the URL from `localhost/samplesite` to `www.clientsite.com` without including `"samplesite"` in the URL?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wordpress local server to live host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8876170/wordpress-local-server-to-live-host)

Comment: read this article http://www.qualitytuts.com/how-to-move-a-wordpress-multisite-from-local-to-web-server/

Answer (score 0):

You can use [All-in-One WP Migration plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/all-in-one-wp-migration/) to export from local and import to the live domain or move one domain to another domain .

Answer (score 0):

When you move the sites over, you need to ensure the base URLs are updated to reflect the live URLs instead of the local ones. There's a couple of ways you can do this, my personal favourite is using constants in the `wp-config.php` file as it's much easier to maintain moving forward.

Add these two lines to the site's `wp-config.php` file before the happy blogging PHP comment which is near the bottom of the file. *Update the URL accordingly*.

```php
define( 'WP_HOME', 'http://example.com' );
define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'http://example.com' );
```

However, you can also go into the `wp_options` table within the database (note the prefix will vary depending on if you changed it on install). Look for the `site_url` and `home_url` values in that table and change the URL to the new, live site address.

Once you have moved the sites over, you should also go to Settings > Permalinks and save the form (you don't have to change anything on that page) and that will flush the rewrite rules so you don't have any local development rewrites still in place.

Generally, you shouldn't be hard coding URLs in the site and most things like WordPress like menus or post links tend to be relative so you don't need to worry about old URLs, but it's worth checking the database over beforehand. There are migration plugins out there that can help mitigate this. [Better Search Replace](https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/better-search-replace/) is a good plugin for this, note ***I am not*** affiliated or endorsed by the plugin/plugin author.

This [WP Beginner article](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-move-wordpress-from-local-server-to-live-site/) has some useful information regarding migrating sites over from local to site states as well. *Again, **I'm not** affiliated or endorsed by that site, and by having a quick read through of it, it gives some useful examples and pictures of some of the things I've mentioned.*

Answer (score 0):

Moving from Localhost to live server is not big deal with WordPress. There are so many ways to migrate your site from one server to other. If you are a beginner and do not have more technical skills then I recommend using WordPress Duplicator Plugin. I use this plugin to migrate my site from localhost to live and also one server to other. It's very easy to migrate WordPress blog using this plugin.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to change in database **wp_options** table. 
Change **site_url** and **home** with your domain name.

Then change in wp_config file for DB Name, Password, username,

After that To change url i have one file just add this file in the root folder and add site url with that file name. and one form will get open add your site url there. and continue.

**Example :**

filename.php : this is the file that i will provide you if you want. **just send your email id**.
it will change url in whole site by search.

https://www.yourdomain.com/filename.php

Definitely this will work in your scenario.