# WordPress navbar links wont work after i migrated from localhost to a live server

Tags: wordpress

I migrated my WordPress site from localhost to a live server and my navigation links don't work.

I have tried the *`velvet blues update url`* plugin and nothing has changed.

I also can't find the `.htaccess` file on my server in the file manager. My links keep redirect me to localhost rather than the live site.

How do I update all of my localhost URLs to point to the live URLs?

Comment: how you‘ve migrated your site? have you changed your site urls while exporting/importing the database? do you have wp-cli installed on your live server?

Comment: it sounds like you have the same problem discussed in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8876170/wordpress-local-server-to-live-host?rq=1). mind the second step of the solution.

Comment: I have updated the urls when exporting database but still the links wont work. I do have a wp-cli on the server but i have uploaded the files manually

Comment: how do you generate your navbar links?

Answer (score 0):

I've had such a problem before and now use [Duplicator](https://wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator/) plugin for migration. If you migrated manually, then go to your online database (once imported) table **wp_options** and change the links to your new domain.

You can reveal the .htaccess file from your cPanel settings as below
[setings change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/745Vl.png)

1. Go to File Manager (Files Section)
2. Click the top-right Settings button.
3. Then on the Preferences window, check the option Show Hidden Files (dotfiles)
4. Confirm the action by clicking the Save button.
5. Now you will see all hidden files (including .htaccess files) in File Manager.

Hope this helps